i can't get the output of my deployment using ingress in the browser
I've set up a Kubernetes cluster using Minikube with an Ingress to access my frontend service. Despite configuring the Ingress and modifying my /etc/hosts file, I'm unable to access the application through the browser. The Ingress controller is running, and all pods are in the correct state, but the application is not accessible via the configured domain (barakatouna.ma).
frontend-deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
  namespace: project-management
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: yazid0hakimi/companymanagement-frontend:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: REACT_APP_API_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: frontend-config
              key: API_URL
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          requests:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "100m"

frontend-service.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
  namespace: project-management
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort

frontend-ingress.yaml:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  namespace: project-management
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: barakatouna.ma
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 80

frontend-configmap.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: frontend-config
  namespace: project-management
data:
  API_URL: "http://backend-service.project-management:8088"
  REACT_APP_ENV: "production"
  REACT_APP_VERSION: "1.0.0"

/etc/hosts file:
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
100.79.128.254 host.docker.internal
100.79.128.254 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
192.168.49.2 barakatouna.ma
# End of section

Steps Taken:

Applied all YAML configurations using kubectl apply -f.
Enabled the Ingress addon in Minikube: minikube addons enable ingress.
Started Minikube tunnel: minikube tunnel.
Added the Minikube IP to /etc/hosts file.

kubectl commands show the Pods are running:
kubectl get all -n project-management
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
pod/backend-deployment-6c6b5997b7-kvxln   1/1     Running   10 (4d1h ago)   6d
pod/debug                                 0/1     Error     0               5d23h
pod/frontend-deployment-86f6fdd77-mtvzw   1/1     Running   2               4d23h
pod/mysql-deployment-79d6c9555b-2k4lx     1/1     Running   6 (4d1h ago)    6d

NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/backend-service       NodePort    10.105.228.71    <none>        8088:31733/TCP   6d
service/frontend-deployment   NodePort    10.101.226.161   <none>        8080:30949/TCP   4d23h
service/frontend-service      NodePort    10.111.235.165   <none>        80:30080/TCP     6d
service/mysql-service         ClusterIP   10.98.97.34      <none>        3306/TCP         6d

NAME                                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/backend-deployment    1/1     1            1           6d
deployment.apps/frontend-deployment   1/1     1            1           5d
deployment.apps/mysql-deployment      1/1     1            1           6d

NAME                                             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/backend-deployment-6c6b5997b7    1         1         1       6d
replicaset.apps/frontend-deployment-7466c844dd   0         0         0       5d
replicaset.apps/frontend-deployment-86f6fdd77    1         1         1       4d23h
replicaset.apps/mysql-deployment-5d97cd759c      0         0         0       6d
replicaset.apps/mysql-deployment-79d6c9555b      1         1         1       6d

I can verify that the Ingress configuration matches my input YAML file:
kubectl get ingress -n project-management -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/"},"name":"frontend-ingress","namespace":"project-management"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"barakatouna.ma","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"frontend-service","port":{"number":80}}},"path":"/","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}]}}
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    creationTimestamp: "2024-08-28T19:48:55Z"
    generation: 1
    name: frontend-ingress
    namespace: project-management
    resourceVersion: "20606"
    uid: 61159641-0439-4549-b0f9-3032ba32e682
  spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    rules:
    - host: barakatouna.ma
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: frontend-service
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.49.2
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""

The ingress controller is running as well:
kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-h5flq        0/1     Completed   0          5d
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-c2jsz         0/1     Completed   0          5d
ingress-nginx-controller-7bf9bf9df7-hd4zv   1/1     Running     0          70m

Minikube IP
minikube ip
192.168.49.2

When trying to access http://barakatouna.ma in the browser, nothing loads. Additionally, running nslookup barakatouna.ma returns:
Server:  192.168.0.1
Address:  192.168.0.1

192.168.0.1 can't find barakatouna.ma: Non-existent domain


What could be preventing the Ingress from routing traffic to my frontend service?
Is there a misconfiguration in my Ingress or Service setup?
How can I troubleshoot why the domain barakatouna.ma is not resolving correctly?
Are there any additional steps or configurations I'm missing to make this work in a Minikube environment?


The Service has type: NodePort; can you access your application through that published port?  The nslookup output indicates you probably haven't registered your domain through a public DNS registry, and trying to add it via /etc/hosts will lead to inconsistent results.  (I'd consider removing the host: from the Ingress configuration.)

yes i can access the application from the port inside the ** minikube ssh**
curl barakatouna.ma gives me the result Im waiting but I cant do that from the browser even if I added the domain in etc/hosts
I removed the host from the ingress configuration

i still dont know what the problem would be !!
everything looks fine

The DNS name you're using isn't defined.  Don't try to make up arbitrary unregistered domain names.  If you remove the host: setting from the Ingress object, can you access the service via minikube tunnel, as described in Set up Ingress on Minikube with the NGINX Ingress Controller?

im following the page you provided and I'm getting this,
inside the minikube ssh,
everything is working fine inside minikube

akatouna.makube:~$
curl --resolve "barakatouna.ma:80:192.168.49.2" -i http://bara
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
